# How can i use PUT and DELETE in ApiResource?

Tags: api, http, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have a users entity in API Platform that i want to restrict access to, using Roles, and allow only *ROLE_ADMIN* to access certain endpoints such as **PUT /users/x** and **DELETE /users/x**, ROLE_USER will be able to access GET only.
The problem is, **POST** and **GET** role restriction works, but when i add **PUT** or **DELETE** they don't work and i face a Symfony error.

Here's part of my user entity:

```
/**
 * Utilisateur
 * 
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"method"="get"},
 *         "post"={"method"="POST", "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')", "access_control_message"="Only admins can post to this entity"},
 *         "delete"={"method"="DELETE", "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')", "access_control_message"="Only admins can update this entity"}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id The user ID
     * 
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @Assert\Uuid
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
```

Error when i get i PUT via Postman:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("There is no builtin action for the collection DELETE operation. You need to define the controller yourself in . (which is being imported from "/srv/api/config/routes/api_platform.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "api_platform" type.").
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually because you are trying to map the `DELETE` action to a `collectionOperation` which is not defined by default. You need to create a custom controller.

I belive it is actually an little mistake and you tried to map it to a `itermOperation`.

Comment: You're right, already solved it though, and found that the problem was i included delete in collectionOperation which doesn't make sense, i included it in itemOperation and everything worked perfectly, thanks for your help.